# PHP - Merge two arrays on same key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'd like to merge two arrays on same key.

Here's the 1st array :

```
Array
(
[2052] => Array
    (
        [495] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [ID_RI_BELANJA] => 79755
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [ID_RI_BELANJA] => 79755
                    )
            )

    )

[4566] => Array
    (
        [488] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [ID_RI_BELANJA] => 231610
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [ID_RI_BELANJA] => 231610
                    )
            )

    )
)
```

And this is the 2nd array

```
Array
(
[2052] => Array
    (
        [495] => Array
            (
                [TOTAL_RI] => 1000000
                [TOTAL_ANGGARAN] => 500000
            )

    )

[4566] => Array
    (
        [488] => Array
            (
                [TOTAL_RI] => 2000000
                [TOTAL_ANGGARAN] => 1000000
            )

    )
)
```

And i'd like merge that two arrays to be like this :

```
Array
(
[2052] => Array
    (
        [495] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [ID_RI_BELANJA] => 79755
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [ID_RI_BELANJA] => 79755
                    )

                [TOTAL_RI] => 1000000
                [TOTAL_ANGGARAN] => 500000
            )

    )

[4566] => Array
    (
        [488] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [ID_RI_BELANJA] => 231610
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [ID_RI_BELANJA] => 231610
                    )

                [TOTAL_RI] => 2000000
                [TOTAL_ANGGARAN] => 1000000
            )

    )
)
```

This is my first project and I don't know what to do.

Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Pls

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging arrays with the same keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881443/merging-arrays-with-the-same-keys)

Answer (score 0):

If your arrays have same Key then:

```
 $array1 = array(); //put your value in this array 
 $array2 = array(); //put your value in this array
 $array3 = array();
 $array3[] = $array1;
 $array3[] = $array2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your two arrays are $array1 and $array 2 respectively, try this:

```
foreach($array1 as $k1 => $v1) {
    foreach($v1 as $k2 => $v2) {
       foreach($v2 as $k3 => $v3) {
          $new[$k1][$k2][$k3] = $array1[$k1][$k2][$k3];
          $new[$k1][$k2] = array_merge($new[$k1][$k2], $array2[$k1][$k2]);
       }
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

=> store the all value in this variable

```
 $Arr1 //put your value in this array 
 $Arr2 //put your value in this array
```

=> And merge it

```
$ResponseDetails    = array_merge( (array)$Arr1, (array)$Arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_replace_recursive` should do the job:

```
// $arr1 is the 1st array, $arr2 - is your 2nd array
$result = array_replace_recursive($arr1, $arr2);  // now the $result variable contains the expected merged result
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php