# How to merge array key in php

Tags: php, arrays

```
array (size=1)
  11 => 
    array (size=1)
      'subject' => 
        array (size=1)
          'Maths' => string '21' (length=2)

array (size=1)
  10 => 
    array (size=1)
      'subject' => 
        array (size=1)
          'Maths' => string '10' (length=2)

array (size=1)
  11 => 
    array (size=1)
      'subject' => 
        array (size=1)
          'Gujarati' => string '21' (length=2)

array (size=1)
  10 => 
    array (size=1)
      'subject' => 
        array (size=1)
          'Gujarati' => string '20' (length=2)
```

array key duplicate like 11 and 10

MY Question: 
How to Create  Below output array .

```
array (size=1)
  11 => 
    array (size=1)
      'subject' => 
        array (size=1)
          'Maths' => string '21' (length=2)
         'Gujarati' => string '21' (length=2)

array (size=1)
  10 => 
    array (size=1)
      'subject' => 
        array (size=1)
          'Maths' => string '10' (length=2)
         'Gujarati' => string '20' (length=2)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging arrays with the same keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881443/merging-arrays-with-the-same-keys)

Comment: @user3528269 I have no idea

Comment: @user3528269 please above output write code

Comment: Please what? read the link it should do what you want, at least from what I understand..

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to get your result. 
Btw: Just asking for help again and again without investigating by yourself is bad behavior, if someone points you to a function (like array_merge_recursive) you should at least take some time to RTM.

```
function array_merge_recursive_new() {

    $arrays = func_get_args();
    $base = array_shift($arrays);

    foreach ($arrays as $array) {
        reset($base); //important
        while (list($key, $value) = @each($array)) {
            if (is_array($value) && @is_array($base[$key])) {
                $base[$key] = array_merge_recursive_new($base[$key], $value);
            } else {
                $base[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    return $base;
}
```

Source/Copyright:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php#106985

I have tested it with these arrays, which should be the same as you have them.

```
$arr1 = array(
    10 => array( "subject" => array("math" => 1)),
    11 => array( "subject" => array("math" => 2)),
);

$arr2 = array(
    10 => array( "subject" => array("guawhatever" => "foo")),
    11 => array( "subject" => array("guawhatever" => "bar")),
);
$blubb = array_merge_recursive_new($arr1,$arr2);
```

Comment: you write code in my question and below output display                 array (size=1)
  11 => 
    array (size=1)
      'subject' => 
        array (size=1)
          'Maths' => string '21' (length=2)
         'Gujarati' => string '21' (length=2)

array (size=1)
  10 => 
    array (size=1)
      'subject' => 
        array (size=1)
          'Maths' => string '10' (length=2)
         'Gujarati' => string '20' (length=2)