# How to combine the same values in an array in foreach loop in php

Tags: php

i want to combine the values of array having same index name in foreach loop..

i tried array_combine but it returns the single array.

```
$data = $_POST['variable']; //it contain the values in an array

$result=array();
  foreach ($data as $mycat){
    $result = array_merge($result, $mycat);
  }
  echo "<pre>";print_r($result);echo "</pre>";
```

it returns only data in single array

```
Array
(
    [vendor] => 1-Open Market
    [priority] => 2
    [demand_for_id] => 9
    [ims_allocation_details_id] => 148
    [temp_demand_id] => 1
)
```

as shown in attached picture item names are same, so when item names are same i want to combine the total values in foreach and insert only one record into database instead to two
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPiMr.jpg)

the contents of **$_POST['variable'];** are

```
Array
(
    
    [2] => Array
        (
            [vendor] => 1-Open Market
            [temp_demand_id] => 6
            [priority] => 1
            [item_name] => BAJRA MOTI
            [amount] => 1000
            [demand_for_id] => 9
            [ims_allocation_details_id] => 153
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [vendor] => 1-Open Market
            [temp_demand_id] => 1
            [priority] => 2
            [item_name] => BAJRA MOTI
            [amount] => 2500
            [demand_for_id] => 9
            [ims_allocation_details_id] => 148
        )

)
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the content of `$_POST['variable']` ? It would help.

Comment: yes let me do it

Comment: I believe your question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5881484/3772849

Comment: @wajdi_jurry dear i checked you suggested link but the solution on that question isn't what i need, as you can see the $_POST['content']; i have same item_name so what i need is combile the total_amount 1000+2500 = 3500 and insert into db only once in foreach loop instead of creating two entries into database

Comment: You are merging associative arrays together, array_merge overwrites duplicate keys as stated in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge). What's the expected result ?

Comment: @AymDev ok so can you please suggest me something that can help me with this situation

Comment: I can't as I don't know what is the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace

```
$result = array_merge($result, $mycat);
```

with

```
$result[] = array_merge($result, $mycat);
```

and it will not be single

**UPDATE**

```
$result = array();
  foreach ($data as $mycat) {
      if(!isset($result[$mycat['item_name']])) {
        $result[$mycat['item_name']] = $mycat;
      } else {
          //do if needed
      }
     
      
  }
  echo "<pre>";print_r($result);echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: its not returning the data in actual format, it its the foreach loop and every time it merge the arrays..

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom function to solve your problem.

Example:

```
<?php
$array = [
    [
        'vendor' => '1-Open Market',
        'temp_demand_id' => 6,
        'priority' => 1,
        'item_name' => 'BAJRA MOTI',
        'amount' => 1000,
        'demand_for_id' => 9,
        'ims_allocation_details_id' => 153,
    ],
    [
        'vendor' => '1-Open Market',
        'temp_demand_id' => 1,
        'priority' => 2,
        'item_name' => 'BAJRA MOTI',
        'amount' => 2500,
        'demand_for_id' => 9,
        'ims_allocation_details_id' => 148,
    ],
    [
        'vendor' => '1-Open Market',
        'temp_demand_id' => 5,
        'priority' => 3,
        'item_name' => 'BAJRA MOTI',
        'amount' => 1000,
        'demand_for_id' => 11,
        'ims_allocation_details_id' => 200,
  ],
];

function array_merge_recursive_custom($array) {
    $processed = null;
    foreach ($array as &$subArray) {
        if (empty($processed)) {
            $processed = $subArray;
            continue;
        }
        foreach ($subArray as $key => $value) {
            if (is_numeric($value)) {
                $subArray[$key] += $processed[$key];
            }
        }
        $processed = $subArray;
    }
    
    return end($array);
}

var_dump(array_merge_recursive_custom($array));
```

Comment: dear @wajdi_jurry thank for your quick help but sorry to say my arrays are not limited to two or three, they are dynamically generated on the bases of check box, if i check two check box and post the form it will generate two arrays if i check more then two check boxes it will generate more then two arrays and all arrays data posted in $data variable

Comment: @UmairMehmood I have updated my answer to work for your case, check it out