# array merge with same key in php

Tags: php

I have Two array both array have same key but I want same key in one array inside multiple value.

Input:

```
[coming_new_date] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2021-03-06
        [1] => 2021-03-07
        [2] => 2021-03-08
        [3] => 2021-03-09
    )

[coming_Day_name] => Array
    (
        [0] => Sat
        [1] => Sun
        [2] => Mon
        [3] => Tue
    )
```

Output:

```
array(

     [0] => array(
                    [0] =>2021-03-06
                    [1] =>Sat
                 )
     [1] => array(
                    [0] =>2021-03-07
                    [1] =>Sun
                 )
      [2] => array(
                       [0] =>2021-03-08
                       [1] =>Mon
                   )
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merging arrays with the same keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881443/merging-arrays-with-the-same-keys)

Comment: doesn't work!!  they work like : Array
(
    [0] => 2021-03-06
    [1] => 2021-03-07
    [2] => 2021-03-08
    [3] => 2021-03-09
    [4] => Sat
    [5] => Sun
    [6] => Mon
    [7] => Tue
)

Comment: You need to write a loop that does what you want. There are no built-in functions that can do what you require.

Comment: @El_Vanja yes. how to do. i will try in loop also but not getting anwer

Comment: If you've tried writing a loop, please edit the question, show your efforts and explain how the result differs from what you need.

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
$output[][]='';

for($i=0; $i<4; $i++)
{
    $output[$i][0]=$coming_new_date[0];
    $output[$i][1]=$coming_day_name[0];
}
```